# Failed on freeze graph for resnet_v1_50 using TF-slim

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I would like to freeze the model and deploy them. I firstly followed the tutorial shipped with slim from [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#exporting-the-inference-graph) and [2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#freezing-the-exported-graph), using InceptionV3, and it was good. Then I am trying to do the same for resnet_v1_50, downloaded from [the provided url](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/resnet_v1_50_2016_08_28.tar.gz).

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Following is the steps:

```
cd /path/to/tensorflow-models/research/slim
# export inference graph, success
python export_inference_graph.py --alsologtostderr --model_name=resnet_v1_50 --output_file=resnet_v1_50_inf_graph.pb
# freeze the inference graph with the trained weights, failed
python ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py \
    --input_graph=resnet_v1_50_inf_graph.pb \
    --input_checkpoint=/path/to/models/resnet_v1_50.ckpt \
    --input_binary=true --output_graph=frozen_resnet_v1_50.pb \
    --output_node_names=resnet_v1_50/predictions/Reshape
```

The error message is too long and I redirect one to refer it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5824#issuecomment-442367921).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the following line suggests, the `labels_offset` should be set to `1` when exporting inference graph.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both 
tensors to match. lhs shape= [1001] rhs shape= [1000]
     [[Node: save/Assign_265 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class= . 
["loc:@resnet_v1_50/logits/biases"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](resnet_v1_50/logits/biases, 
save/RestoreV2_265/_1)]]
```

The command will be like:

```
python export_inference_graph.py --model_name=resnet_v1_50 --labels_offset=1 --output_file=resnet_v1_50_inf_graph.pb
```